# Using a predicted variable as a predictor

Tags: estimation, modeling, uncertainty

Is it legit to use predicted observations in a variable as a predictor or is this introducing a lot of uncertainty in the specific model?

Comment: it depends on what you are talking about. Please provide more details.

Comment: It's to first predict with a certain response in one model and then including this predicted variable in another model which tries to predict another response

Comment: Yes, I got that from your question, but context matters. What kind of study are we talking about? Economics? Biomedical? What kind of data do you have (both the first predicted value and the second)? How do you handle your prediction (as predicted group membership, probability or as a continuous value)? etc...?

Comment: It's a financial problem; the first problem is to predict "time until default" and the second is to predict Loss Given Default. The first model is a Cox and the second is a GBM. Both of the responses are binary and there are approximately 110 000 instances